# AutoPlay a slider with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have the code following where I am unable to add Autoplay on the slider. Can anyone help me with this?

```
$('#front-slides').slides({
        preload: true,
        generateNextPrev: false,
        slideSpeed: 500,
        animationStart: function(current){
            $slideCaption = $(".slides_container div.slide:eq("+ (current-1) +") .caption").text();
            $("#headline h6").text($slideCaption);

            if($slideCaption != ''){
                $("#headline").stop().hide().slideDown(600);
            }else{
                $("#headline").hide();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add following lines  under the  slideSpeed: 500,

```
    play: 5000,
    pause: 2500,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(function() { 
      $(".slider").jCarouselLite({
      auto:500,
      speed:800,
      btnNext: ".next",                     
      btnPrev: ".prev",                     
      visible: 5                 
     });             
});
```